# ¿cómo compilar un package java en sublime text 3?

Tags: java, sublimetext3

Estoy probando Sublime text para aprender Java usando esta configuración en el sublime-build

```
{
  "cmd": "javac ${file_name} && java ${file_base_name}",
  "shell": true
}
```

Todo va bien al compilar y ejecutar un archivo. El problema surge al crear paquetes (package). Ahora solo compila y crea el archivo.class pero ya no ejecuta el archivo.

[image: Sin package compila y ejecuta correctamente]

[image: Con package compila pero no ejecuta. Y muestra 'Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal Prueba']

Ese es el primer problema que tengo ahora. Si me pueden ayudar en solucionarlo o aclarar porque me sale este error estaré muy agradecido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Compilar y Ejecutar Aplicaciones Java Incluyendo Packages

Bien, el archivo .sublime-build hace ejecutar los 2 comandos:
`javac \"$file_name\"` y después el `java \"$file_base_name\"`, lo cual está bien cuando tanto los archivos .class y .java están mezclados en el mismo directorio (lo cual no se recomienda).

Para compilar con packages, se deben especificar las rutas a los binarios y los fuentes, por ejemplo, en linea de comandos y suponiendo que el proyecto esta organizado así:

```
miProyecto/bin/com/java/prueba/Prueba.class
miProyecto/src/com/java/prueba/Prueba.java
```

1. Se crea una variable para el classpath:

   `$ export CLASSPATH=~/miProyecto/bin`
2. Luego la variable para los fuentes:

   `$ export SOURCES=~/miProyecto/src/com/java`
3. Después la compilación:

   `$ javac -sourcepath com -d ${CLASSPATH} ${SOURCES}/*/*.java`
4. Finalmente la ejecucion:

   `$ java com/java/prueba/Prueba`

Los 4 anteriores comandos son los que debes implementar en el archivo .sublime-build

### *Mi configuración:*

[image: build]

```
"cmd": ["export CLASSPATH=\"$folder/bin\" && export SOURCES=\"$folder/src/com/java\" && javac -sourcepath com -d \\${CLASSPATH} \\${SOURCES}/*/*.java && java com/java/\"\\${PWD##*/}\"/\"$file_base_name\""],
```

### *Notas Importantes:*

- Probado en entornos UNIX sin problemas.
- Mi configuración la basé en el sistema de directorios de Eclipse, es decir, organizando los paquetes de los .class en un directorio 'bin' y los paquetes de los .java en 'src'.

### *Ejecución:*

[image: output]

Como resultado, un frame simple y un thread que va imprimiendo en la consola el estado de un conteo.

### *Herramientas Usadas:*

- Sublime Text 3 (build 3126)
- Java 1.8.0_31
- Linux y OS X

Comment: Todo claro y buen aporte. Pero queda como siempre lo imaginé: no es dinámico a la estructura de carpetas que tenga en el proyecto actual. Si cambio de espacio de trabajo tengo que setear las variables a mi nueva estructura de carpetas. Pero ¿no hay manera de hacer que reconozca mi directorio actual cuando abro el sublime como un proyecto y no como archivo solamente? No sé si me hago entender.

Comment: Ok, prueba Javatar, plugin para ST3 https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Javatar

Answer (score 0):

Cuando compilas con package te crea tambien las carpetas del package por lo que es probable que estes apuntando la ejecucion al raiz y no al path correcto.

Comment: Si. Ahora que lo dices me acaba de pasar algo que comprueba lo que dices. Entonces ¿cómo debería corregir la configuración?

Comment: Basicamente tendras que apuntar ${file_base_name} a la nueva ruta.

Comment: Es es fácil decir y ya lo había pensado. El problema está en que no sé como continuar indicar más carpetas a partir de la variable que usa sublime como el ${file_base_name}.
Pero la variable que quiero usar es '$project_path' que según he leido en otra pagina apunta al directorio del proyecto activo. Supongo que se refiere a donde estoy trabajando e indicado como proyecto al ST3. Entonces a partir de eso quiero agregarle a nueva carpeta donde buscar el '.class'. Y estado he probado hacerlo así '${project_path}/carpeta'  pero algo está mal.

Answer (score 0):

Como podrás comprobar si compilas el código con la herramienta JavaC que trae por defecto SublimeText compilará tu código sin problema. (Pero como ya sabrás no lo ejecutará algo que siempre será mejor hacer con un Terminal)

Comment: El código JSON que puse no es el que viene por defecto en ST3. Este es otro que si compila y ejecuta tal como puedes ver en la primera imagen. Fijate que puse '&& java' y no todo está con 'javac'. El problema es que al usar paquetes no encontraba el '.class'. Y la explicación de eso está en el primer comentario. Ahora solo falta modificar el JSON para que el comando ''java' se ubique en la carpeta donde se crea el '.class'.

Comment: Claro, a eso me refiero, si usas el que viene por defecto funciona perfectamente a la hora de compilar los package. Busca el archivo del build-in de JavaC y añade la llamada a ´java´ de la que hablabas.

Comment: Esa es buena idea. Pero ahora que lo mencionas recién caigo en cuenta que no se dónde está el archivo 'JavaC' para poder editarlo. Solo lo puedo seleccionar para usarlo.

Comment: @HectorCcasaniPerdidaMente justo en ese punto me quede yo, encuentralo y solucionarás el problema. Por mi parte si lo encuentro te lo diré.