# correr mi app de Java desde una terminal me da error package does not exist

Tags: java, terminal

He estado durante 2 días intentando usar [javac](/questions/tagged/javac) Y Javatar  solo para correr una app que hice en [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) desde la consola pero no he tenido éxito.

Usando estas guias
https://platzi.com/java-basico-2015/tutoriales/compilar-y-ejecutar-java-con-sublime-text-3/
y consultando otras respuestas de [¿cómo compilar un package java en sublime text 3?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44204/c%C3%B3mo-compilar-un-package-java-en-sublime-text-3) he logrado poner en marcha un fichero de java sin imports desde el sublime y desde la consola, pero cuando le coloco imports deja de funcionar.

El error:

```
error: package modelos does not exist
error: cannot find symbol
```

Con javatar ocurre exactamente lo mismo.
[image: Con javatar ocurre exactamente lo mismo]

Cuando compilo Un archivo *.java que viene solo sin importar paquetes, funciona y se compila correctamente pero cuando viene con imports, deja de funcionar y pasa el mismo error, por lo cual sospecho que javatar y javaC no esta usando los directorios de clases de los imports.

**La pregunta es**

Que otras alternativas tengo para poder correr mi app de Java desde una terminal de windows o linux nativa? o si es el caso como puedo configurar el sublime o cualquier otro editor de texto para hacer dicha labor de compilar y ejecutar la app?

### Solucion!

gracias a [sjuan76][2]

Crear un archivo bat con las siguientes instrucciones. 

    `set CLASSPATH=#Aqui la ruta de salida de lo que se va a compilar.
    javac -d %CLASSPATH% @clases.txt
    cd %CLASSPATH% 
    java #direccion del fichero a ejecutar.`

luego ese archivo conectarlo al build config de Sublime o correrlo directamente desde la terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema no es de los packages, el problema es de tener múltiples ficheros.

Cuando haces `javac controladores/ClaseA.java`, buscará la clase indicada en `import modulos.ClaseB`.

Pero esa clase *aún no está compilada*, así que no la encuentra (ni el package).

La solución es compilar **todas** las clases a la vez. Como por línea de comandos puede ser engorroso e incluso pasarse de los límites de longitud de comandos, puedes crear un archivo de texto que contenga los nombre de todas las clases a compilar y pasarlo indicándolo con `@`:

```
Fichero clases.txt:

controladores/ClaseA.java
modulos/ClaseB.java

Compilación: javac @clases.txt
```

Y antes de que lo digas, sí, es pelín engorroso. Pero es que casi nadie usa `javac` directamente, incluso para línea de comandos se usan herrmaientas como `ant` o `maven`.

Comment: Bueno si es mejor mucho mejor usar ant o maven. como se puede hacer desde alli?
La idea era buscar una alternativa a todo..

Comment: Este sitio es para preguntas específicas. Hacerte un tutorial de `apache ant` (te recomiendo que empieces por `ant`, es más sencillo) sería muy largo, incompleto y daría menos información que los tutoriales que ya existen. Busca los ejemplos (por ejemplo de la propia página de la *Apache Foundation*), pruébalos y si tienes errores entonces plantea la pregunta. Recuerda que al poner código en la pregunta queremos que esté como texto, y que las capturas de pantalla mejor si tienen suficiente definición para que se puedan leer.

Comment: +1 Igual Me gusta esa forma de solucionar el problema.